# Can an animated SVG render on a canvas without the canvas re-rendering?

Tags: animation, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to add an animated SVG to a canvas so that the SVG would keep animating in an endless loop without the canvas needing to re-render. 
Is that possible at all? 
I tried to use drawImage to draw a canvas onto another but it would only update my SVG animation when the whole canvas re-renders.

Comment: No. Animations on canvas can only work if you redraw every single frame.

Comment: And note that even calling multiple times drawImage with the same image should not work. [Only the first frame of an animated image should ever be drawn](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts:canvasimagesource-3). This is a [webkit/chrome bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74779), and they may fix it some day.

Comment: That's too bad thx. So would you suggest to have the whole canvas re-render constantly even if it's just a small SVG in it that has constant animation?
Or is it better to have the SVG hover over the canvas with CSS?